# Is it possible to move the checkerboard pieces with the hasClass and the addClass?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var cells = $(".cell");
    var colorCount = 0; 

    for (var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++)
    {
        var cell = $(cells[i]);
        var isDark = colorCount % 2 == 0;
        var isNextRow = (i + 1) % 8 == 0;
        colorCount += isNextRow ? 2 : 1;
        cell.css("background-color", isDark ? "navy" : "white"); 
    }
    $(".cell.piece.red").on({
        click: function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "yellow"); }
    });
    $(".cell.piece.black").on({
        click: function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");  }
    });
      
     
});
```

```css
.home > .board
{
    display: table;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.home > .board > .row
{
    display: table;
}

.home > .board > .row > .cell
{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}

.piece
{
    background-size: 75px 75px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-origin: content-box;
}

.red
{
    background-image: URL('../images/red.png');
}

.black
{
    background-image: URL('../images/black.png');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home">
            
                <div class="board">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece red"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                        <div class="cell"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                        <div class="cell piece black"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

I have this red and black checkerboard pieces on a checkerboard, but how do I get them to move. For example, if I wanted to move the first checkerboard red piece to the seventeenth cell how would I do that? To clarify, what I want to be done is when I click on the first red highlighted checkerboard piece, I want that to move to next closet unoccupied cell, which in my case would be the seventeenth cell of the checkerboard. Please any examples with any elements on the checkerboard would be much appreciated in order for me to fully learn how to move the checkerboard pieces.  I have my three files which are a JavaScript file, CSS file, and HTML file.

Comment: @ Jaromanda X I mean I want the very  first red checker piece to be moved to the seventeenth cell

Comment: @Jaromanda I working only with JQuery. I understand what you're saying though. Could you demonsrate an example

Comment: @ Jaromanda X I mean I don't want no animation just when I click on the very first red checker piece I want it to move to seventeenth cell. That's all

Comment: @ Jaromanda X I want to learn the complex Jquery. How else will I ever get better at programming

Comment: jQuery is a javascript library, you can't use jQuery without knowing javascript - perhaps that's an issue you need to remedy - jQuery makes DOM manipulation easy - it's not a substitute for javascript

Comment: @Jaromanda X I know how it can be done in JavaScript, but how can I use the addClass and hasClass method to do it in JQuery? Any examples

Comment: @Jaromanda X no examples?

Comment: @Jaromanda X Yes, do you think you could show me a small example? I just want to learn the basis of JQuery

Comment: @ Jaromanda X I am learning. I have put in a lot of effort. Please try to be patient with me. Everybody that is new at programming doesn't have to be smart at. These concepts are sometimes not easy applied when you get into more complex coding. I am quite sure you know this

Comment: @ Jaromanda X Moving the very first red checker piece to the seventeenth cell. My original question.

Comment: @  Jaromanda  I working on this now